# How do I restrict a jquery script to the size of the container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a gallery and buttons to control the gallery as well. I am a newbie to jquery and used a small script to change the margin by a fixed amount on a div container. The script works great but it extends past the top and bottom of the div contents. I would set a specific size to the div, but the idea is to use this on multiple pages with varying amounts of content. 
How do I restrict the the button function to not expand past the content inside the div?

```
 $('.scrolltdup').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.wrap').animate({
    marginTop: "+=160px"
  }, "fast");
 });

$('.scrolltddown').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.wrap').animate({
    marginTop: "-=160px"
  }, "fast");
});
```

I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2LcumL6p/3/) with the page content I have. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is my first from scratch site using html5, CSS3 and jquery. It's a learning experience. :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something that comes to mind as a possible solution... Get the height of the container element and check after each button click if the animation will go "out-of-bounds" relative to the container height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add some if statements:

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2LcumL6p/4/

```
$('.scrolltdup').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (parseInt($('.wrap').css('margin-top')) < 0) {
        $('.wrap').animate({
            marginTop: "+=160px"
        }, "fast");
    }
});

$('.scrolltddown').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (parseInt($('.wrap').css('margin-top')) > -($('.wrap').height() - 160)) {
        $('.wrap').animate({
            marginTop: "-=160px"
        }, "fast");
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. With the IF statement its still allows to site to reflow to different display sizes as well.. Thank you for all the quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

The container is a fixed shape, showing 3 visible boxes at once, so you can get the number of sets of 3 with `var totalRows = Math.max( $(".box").length / 3 )`.

From there, you can extrapolate the max marginTop before you run out of projects, and just test the marginTop before animating. The most minimal way to detect maxScroll and minScroll on page load (setting them to the maximum and minimum `marginTop`s), and then drop a ternary operator into your animate code.

Change `marginTop: "+=160px"`

To `marginTop: "+=" + ( $(".wrap").css( "margin-top" ) > maxScroll ? "0px" : "160px"`;

and do the same for `marginTop: "-=160px"` .

Answer (score 0):

Considering Each Row will have two Div with class box here is a working code that will find the max height of the two div and animate accordingly

```
var presentRow=1;
function getHeight(elem1,elem2){
  return Math.max($(elem1).outerHeight(),$(elem2).outerHeight())+10;
}

$('.scrolltdup').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      height=getHeight($(".wrap .box:nth-child("+presentRow+")"),$(".wrap .box:nth-child("+(presentRow+1)+")")); 
      $('.wrap').animate({
        marginTop: "+="+height+"px"
      }, "fast",function(){
          presentRow=presentRow-2;
      });

   });
   $('.scrolltddown').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

 height=getHeight($(".wrap .box:nth-child("+presentRow+")"),$(".wrap .box:nth-child("+(presentRow+1)+")")); 
      $('.wrap').animate({
        marginTop: "-="+height+"px"
      }, "fast",function(){
          presentRow=presentRow+2;
      });
   });
```

You can add some validation too by checking the presentRow variable.